# Experience Manager and Session Preview DB issue

Tags: 2013, experience-manager, dd4t, session-preview, database

I'm running SDL Tridion 2013 with Experience Manager and DD4T. Everything works fine except for the Session Preview.

The odd thing is when I check the Session Preview DB for the CPs that were just edited they are there when I click on update preview. Now the odd thing is that the Publication ID of the CPs are incorrect. If I have a clean Session Preview DB, the first insert is correct. After the first time I click Update Preview it seems to increment the Publication ID.

Has anyone seen this before? The `PREVIEW_SESSION_OBJECT_KEY` in the `PREVIEW_SESSION_ITEMS` table has the correct information for the items.

Comment: What exactly is not working with session preview? I would suggest to forget about the data in the DB for now and edit your question with the actual (functional) issue in there.

Comment: Temporary data has different publication ids by design, and this is fine - the product and APIs cope with it. Is something not working?

Comment: I have seen the same behavior in other Storage Wrapper like Undo, as @NunoLinhares is mentioning it is by design.

Comment: @piti-itharat did the answer I gave help you at all?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing to check is if the PreviewContentModule is DISABLED! This is not needed with a DD4T implementation, and will in fact prevent the session preview from working.

So if the  section of your Web.config contains this module, please comment it out and try again.

Comment: Please confirm for DD4T (JAVA) to check PreviewContentModule is DISABLED, which file/files needs to be checked